# How to delete multiple list items in SharePoint Online?

Tags: bulk

Is it possible to delete multiple items in SharePoint Online. I mean more than 5k items with 2 clicks.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed after creating a Flow with 2 steps:

1. Get items from SharePoint list
2. Delete each item ID by ID

Answer (score 0):

Create two views - so that you can split & display the data then bulk delete.

Comment: I dont think is going to work. Thanks anyway